# Сhange max_routes

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

Where can I change max_routes in openstask?
Via CLI or config file?

Answer (score 1):

max_routes is a [configuration setting](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/latest/configuration/neutron.html#DEFAULT.max_routes).